# What are some of the known issues when migrating from .net framework 4.5.2 to 4.6.2?

Tags: .net, migration

As the question states, i am looking to upgrade my .net project from 4.5.2 to 4.6.2
For a start, i have been looking at this article by Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/

Looking into the links within as well but it feels overwhelming and im not even sure where to begin.

Can anyone provide any suggestion on where i can start or how to perform this migration please?